# I'm looking to move cells with color highlighted to different sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm looking to copy the cells highlighted in particular color to the different sheet in one column.

Sample doc: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xa_WKlmHO5mT688zM0O-LXlqnSbITG2YK1uLPq5XzcA/edit#gid=328987545

Can you help me with the script to get desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values of the highlighted cells (From your provided Spreadsheet, it's `#ffff00`), and want to put the values to the column "A" of destination sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // This is from your sample Spreadsheet.
  const dstSheetName = "Ouput"; // This is from your sample Spreadsheet.
  const checkColor = "#ffff00"; // This is from your sample Spreadsheet.

  // Retrieve sheets.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [src, dst] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // Retrieve source values and backgrounds.
  const srcRange = src.getDataRange();
  const backgrounds = srcRange.getBackgrounds();

  // Create an array for putting to the destination sheet.
  const values = srcRange.getValues().reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      if (backgrounds[i][j] == checkColor) {
        ar.push([c]);
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // Put the array to the column "A" of the destination sheet.
  dst.getRange(1, 1, values.length).setValues(values).setBackground(checkColor);
}
```

- When this script is run, the values are retrieved from the highlighted cells of the source sheet. And, the retrieved values are put to the column "A" of the destination sheet.
- From your sample Spreadsheet, the destination sheet has the highlighted cells. So, I added `setBackground(checkColor)`. If you don't want to set the color, please remove it.

#### References:

- [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)
- [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: @Tony About your new question of `Is there anyway we can remove duplicates? It has to detect only 1st come of all range and add output sheet`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?